# Angular - Async Pipe and Search

Tags: angular, observable, angular-httpclient, angular-pipe, angular-observable

I know that this is totally wrong.... But I can't find an example to implement it

```
search = '';
ngOnInit() {
    this.countries$ = this.areasService.getCountries(this.search); //HttpClient request
}

search(key) {
    this.search = key;
    this.countries$.next();
}

<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let c of (countries$ | async)?.docs">{{c.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have a list of countries and one input to search by name

Comment: So you want to recall the get countries function each time the search changes?

Comment: yes..... i thought that this.countries$.next(); is correct... but next is not a function is the error

Comment: Next is a function for an observer if you want you can do a switchmap and create a subject inside that you call next on, but I think that's basically the answer given below.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to subscribe AND publish into an observable, you can use Subject.

With this in mind, you can trigger your http call, and broadcast the new value to your subject.

```
search = '';
countries$ = new Subject();
ngOnInit() {
    this.refreshCountries();
}

search(key) {
    this.search = key;
    this.refreshCountries();
}

refreshCountries(){
    this.areasService.getCountries(this.search)
       .subscribe((value) => {
         if(value && value.docs){
            console.log('received docs =', value.docs);
            this.countries$.next(value.docs)); //HttpClient request
         }
}

<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let c of (countries$ | async)">{{c.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Note : In order to reduce the number of requests you make (which is a problem that you will face soon), you can use debounceTime

Comment: what is the difference with "this.countries$ = this.areasService.getCountries(this.search);"

Comment: this.countries$ = this.areasService.getCountries(this.search); is an assignment, you change the nature of his.countries$ what I wrote is called broadcasting, you emit a new value inside it.

Comment: @Michalis In essence, yes. Because that what you do : make an http call and publish the new value into the Observer. You could refactor the command into a function that you call twice, but fundamentaly, you will end up doing the same thing.

Comment: I try the code.... it execute new request.... but it doesn't change the async pipe

Comment: @Michalis could you post the code that triggers "search" ?  Also, can you check that the areasService is firing at each search ?

Comment: (click)="search('demo')"

Comment: it's just a click event

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183061/discussion-between-madjaoue-and-michalis).

Comment: I can also see the http request at network... with the correct response